Magnetic compass working on the Moon and the Mars planet
Mars planet
Moon
Magnetic compass
Theoretically and practically, will a magnetic compass work on the Moon and the Mars planet?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field_of_the_Moon

Moon doesn't have active geodynamo, just local magnetized groups in crust, so compass will not work on Moon and on Mars either because it's dynamo is stopped also. However you could use it for finding magnetized crust parts in Moon/Mars probably.

Thanks.
Can a customised magnetic compass designed and constructed may assist on Mars planet?
